# Customize Landing pages

Tags: docusignapi

I am using SOAP API to send the envelopes. I see that once the signing is complete, the user gets redirected to the URL specified under Branding -> Sign Complete.

Is there a way to customize the "You have completed your documents" popup which shows up on the DocuSignComplete.aspx page. We do not want our users to see the Docusign sign up form on this popup. We would like to display our company related information which does not come up until the user clicks on the "X" button on this popup.

Let us know if we should contact Account Manager to process this request.

Thanks
Naresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (prepended to original Answer):**

[My apologies -- I should have included this information in my original answer. Information in my original answer still applies, but the setting described here addresses another part of your question.]

To remove the "create an account or login" form (and related content) that's displayed in the "Signing Complete" popup window, login to DocuSign as an Administrator, navigate to **Preferences >> Features**, and uncheck this box:

[image: Feature setting]

**Original Answer:**

In general, many components of the "Signing Complete" popup window can be customized by modifying the **Signing Resource file**.  That being said though, customizations are for the most part limited to things like hiding/showing certain elements, and changing string values that appear in certain places within that window.  For example:

- `<data name="DocuSignComplete_ShowSocialNetworks">true</data>` --> this element determines whether or not the Social Media content is displayed in the right pane of the window.
- `<data name="DocuSignComplete_Success">You have completed your documents</data>` --> This element can be used to customize the string value that appears within the window.

So, while customization of this window is possible, you're fairly limited as to the types of things you can customize.  See the Account Branding guide for information about how/where to access Resource files: http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Account%20Branding.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After implementing, if the user has a DocuSign Account they still get a popup saying "LOG IN TO DOCUSIGN". Is there a way to skip this Popup?