# Skip LOG IN TO DOCUSIGN popup after signing

Tags: docusignapi

I turned off the feature "Signer can create account" to get rid of that popup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616609/1015686

After signing the document, if the email of the user signing the DocuSign document has a DocuSign account, they get the following popup:

LOG IN TO DOCUSIGN

A copy of this document has been saved to your DocuSign account. Please log in to view it.

Is there any way to disable this popup, or skip it?

[image: Log in to DocuSign Popup after signing]

Comment: I believe the short answer is no, cannot disable/skip. This is where flexibility and some control is given to the signer w/a DocuSign account, as opposed to the sender dictating the entire experience. The only way to 'skip' this is if you are doing embedded signing, which is a totally different paradigm then the remote signing you have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the short answer is no, cannot disable/skip. This is where flexibility and some control is given to the signer w/a DocuSign account, as opposed to the sender dictating the entire experience. The only way to 'skip' this is if you are doing embedded signing, which is a totally different paradigm then the remote signing you have above.