# How to prevent login to account prompt while remote docuisign

Tags: php, docusignapi

In remote signing (docusign send to email), after finish sign asking for login to account and if click 'no thanks' then only it is redirecting to branded destination url otherwise not getting the envelope details in our application. I disabled recipient authentication in signing setting and security , but still coming. So How to prevent login prompt to popup while signing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Settings" (DocuSign Admin) and find Signing Settings at the left and uncheck "Allow Recipients to Create a DocuSign Account"
[image]

Comment: I unchecked, but still getting login prompt after DocuSign remote signing. Is there any other way to hide that?

Comment: Did you log out, log in (maybe use a fresh new browser instant), then, sent a new envelope ?

Comment: Yes I logout and logged in . But still I am getting login prompt with dousign remote sign from email and also if the user click 'no thanks ' then only the page is redirecting to our application(as I have given destination url in brand). So I have to remove login popup as I have to redirect to our application on click 'Finish' button. I have attached the screenshot with the question.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't understand your question. You can't do this actually

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060694/skip-log-in-to-docusign-popup-after-signing